# Updating Parse Server Example in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I have managed to use Parse Server on Heroku for quite sometime now using this guide.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku

however I would like to use the dashboard but my parse server is 1.6, is there a way to update my parse server from heroku?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you deployed parse-server to Heroku simply by using the `Deploy` button on the Heroku website. If so you can manually fetch the changes of parse-server-example from the original repository onto you computer and push them back to heroku.

1. Clone the current deployment of parse-server from Heroku to your computer
2. Add the original parse-server-example as a remote repository from `https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example.git`
3. Fetch the changes from the remote repository that you've added
4. Merge
5. Push to heroku

### Note:

Parse Server is currently at 2.2.9. If you have a live app it would be recommendable to test if your app still works after the update in a test environment prior to the production environment .